# How can i skip message by date using masstransit c#

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a fanout exchange and distributed queues. If the sentTime exceeds two minutes, I want message to come to the consumer. If it doesn't exceed two minutes, I want to hold the message in the queue.

I tried filtering as below but if the filter is not valid the message is consumed. Is there a way to bypass this on masstransit?

[MassTransit Filtering messages a consumer can handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198716/masstransit-filtering-messages-a-consumer-can-handle)

I would like to say that each queue has a multiple consumer. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delay the delivery of a message to a consumer, you can use the delayed message delivery feature of the transport to schedule it for two minutes in the future. MassTransit also supports scheduling messages via Quartz.NET or Hangfire if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Messages will be queued from 100+ independent servers. So that means too much effort for hangfire or quartz, which doesn't work for me. Isn't there a simpler way? Skipping it while filtering solves my problem.

Comment: Consume them in a consumer, and if it isn't time yet, schedule them for delayed redelivery using a separate queue. If you're using Azure or Amazon, those delivery delays are built-in to the transport. With RabbitMQ, you'd need the delayed exchange plug-in installed, but the same end result to delay delivery using a separate queue.